# Error 503 when preview a template email with header_template or footer_template config_path

Tags: magento2, template, email-templates, newsletter

When I try to show the preview of my newsletter template I get error 503:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

This happens only when I use one or both these magento directives:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Check Your Custom Template Code!

Comment: It also happens with only these 2 lines.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the directive because I tried to delete all the phtml content and I get the same error. How to check that the config_path is right?

Comment: Go to Marketing > Email Templates then Add A New Template. Select Header or Footer from the Template dropdown then Load Template. What happens? Do you also have any Apache or PHP logs?